# Fazer INSERT usando métodos e classes no banco de dados C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, classes, método

Olá, boa tarde! O meu problema é o seguinte: Estou querendo executar um evento de Inserir, que no banco de dados vai adicionar o (nome, usuario, setor, cargo, turno e ramal), porém agora estou treinando executar essa função em um método de uma classe ao invés de direto no evento do click. Só que criei também uma classe de Conexao para fazer o SELECT dos dados e enviar para a estrutura Repeater... 
 O caso é: No evento do botão inserir eu tenho

```
protected void btnInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InserirF insF = new InserirF();
    ConexaoF conF = new ConexaoF();

    conF.Nome = txtNome.Text;
    conF.Usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
    conF.Setor = txtSetor.Text;
    conF.Cargo = txtCargo.Text;
    conF.Turno = txtTurno.Text;
    conF.Ramal = txtRamal.Text;
    insF.Inserir();
}
```

Agora veja que na minha classe de Conexao eu tenho o seguinte

```
public class ConexaoF {


string id;
string nome; string usuario; string setor; string cargo; string turno; string ramal;

public string ID
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
}
public string Nome
{
    get { return nome; }
    set { nome = value; }
}
public string Usuario
{
    get { return usuario; }
    set { usuario = value; }
}
public string Setor
{
    get { return setor; }
    set { setor = value; }
}
public string Cargo
{
    get { return cargo; }
    set { cargo = value; }
}
public string Turno
{
    get { return turno; }
    set { turno = value; }
}
public string Ramal
{
    get { return ramal; }
    set { ramal = value; }
}

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString);

public List<ConexaoF> listar()
{
    List<ConexaoF> listaresultado = new List<ConexaoF>();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand sqlSeleciona = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, nome, usuario, setor, cargo, turno, ramal FROM spc_funcionario_aprendiz ORDER BY id ASC", sqlConnection);

        sqlConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = sqlSeleciona.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ConexaoF conn = new ConexaoF();

            conn.id = dr["id"].ToString();
            conn.nome = dr["nome"].ToString();
            conn.usuario = dr["usuario"].ToString();
            conn.setor = dr["setor"].ToString();
            conn.cargo = dr["cargo"].ToString();
            conn.turno = dr["turno"].ToString();
            conn.ramal = dr["ramal"].ToString();

            listaresultado.Add(conn);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    return listaresultado;
}}
```

Ignorem as chaves, pois tive problemas para inserir o código. 
 enfim, aqui na classe Conexao eu tenho os dados de Nome, Usuario, Setor, Cargo, Turno e Ramal, que respectivamente eu vou utilizar tanto no evento do click Inserir tanto quanto na outra classe InserirF que vem o método que faz o Insert. Segue o código da classe InsertF

```
public class InserirF {


SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString);

public void Inserir()
{
    ConexaoF conF = new ConexaoF();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand sqlInserir = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO spc_funcionario_aprendiz (nome, usuario, setor, cargo, turno, ramal) VALUES ('@nome', '@usuario', '@setor', '@cargo', '@turno', '@ramal')", sqlConnection);
        sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("nome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Nome.ToString();
        sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Usuario.ToString();
        sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("setor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Setor.ToString();
        sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("cargo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Cargo.ToString();
        sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("turno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Turno.ToString();
        sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("ramal", SqlDbType.Int).Value = conF.Ramal.ToString();

        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlInserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}}
```

Só que, perceba que ao clicar no botão, os eventos de 
`conF.Nome = txtNome.Text;
conF.Usuario = txtUsuario.Text;` 
E adiante, eles recebem o valor que está no TextBox, porém após isso, quando entra o método `insF.Insert()` ele acaba "reiniciando" toda as informações da ConexaoF conF, pois acaba criando outra no início do método.. E assim respectivamente deixando os dados nulos, dando erro no INSERT. Como é possível salvar esses valores para que eu possa usar eles no SqlCommand INSERT?

Comment: Seria bom reduzir tudo a um [mcve] do problema, para que a pergunta sirva para um público amplo. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

//Está gerando novos valores porque você está dando  new Conexão em -->  //"ConexaoF conF = new ConexaoF();"

protected void btnInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

```
InserirF insF = new InserirF();
ConexaoF conF = new ConexaoF();

conF.Nome = txtNome.Text;
conF.Usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
conF.Setor = txtSetor.Text;
conF.Cargo = txtCargo.Text;
conF.Turno = txtTurno.Text;
conF.Ramal = txtRamal.Text;
```

// Passe o conf por referência

```
insF.Inserir(conf);
```

}

//e aqui, você recebe essa referência. (TIRANDO O ConexaoF conF = new ConexaoF())

public void Inserir(ConexaoF conf)
{

```
try
{
    SqlCommand sqlInserir = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO spc_funcionario_aprendiz (nome, usuario, setor, cargo, turno, ramal) VALUES ('@nome', '@usuario', '@setor', '@cargo', '@turno', '@ramal')", sqlConnection);
    sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("nome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Nome.ToString();
    sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Usuario.ToString();
    sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("setor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Setor.ToString();
    sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("cargo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Cargo.ToString();
    sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("turno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = conF.Turno.ToString();
    sqlInserir.Parameters.Add("ramal", SqlDbType.Int).Value = conF.Ramal.ToString();

    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlInserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
finally
{
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: Opa, deu certinho! Muito obrigado, ajudou muito.. Foi mais simples do que eu esperava

Comment: Opa, por nada :)